# How is background of 2.5d games developed

Tags: 3d, platformer, 2.5d

When I say 2.5d games, I mean like this:

[Bloodstained Ritual of the Night DEMO gameplay](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W_HTF0eUhb8)

My question is, I know the characters and platforms are 3d but are the backgrounds all 3d as well? Even if its not interacted on in any way? Like for example, at 10:45, did the developer(s) make models of the cannons at the background? Or 48:30, did they model the houses?

For context, I'm starting a hobby project game in 2.5d and I'm trying to get an idea on how I would develop the backgrounds.

Comment: Hello and welcome to GDSE. Sadly, your question is offtopic, since we most likely weren't involved in creating the game and so we can't really be sure either. For all we know, it could have been the effect used in Ocarina of Time or Resident Evil, where prerendered backgrounds were scrolled from side to side.

Comment: As Bálint says, we generally can't tell you how a particular thing is done in "games," since each game can vary so widely, and usually only the developers of a specific title know exactly what techniques they use. But we can help you solve problems in *your* game. How have you tried making your backgrounds so far? Is there anything in particular about the process or the results with which you're unsatisfied? Tell us about that, and we can try to help you find solutions to that issue that will work for your game project, regardless of whether that's how Bloodstained Ritual of the Night did it.

Comment: This game isn't 2.5d though, it's still fully on the x/y axis making it a 2d game with a 3d coating. This game can be fully realised in 2D without changing gameplay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both of these seem to be 3d models rendered in real-time. If they were pre-rendered or hand-drawn 2d textures, then it wouldn't be possible to see [the cannons](https://youtu.be/W_HTF0eUhb8?t=650) from different angles while the camera moves. And if [the house](https://youtu.be/W_HTF0eUhb8?t=2903) was just a static background texture, then it wouldn't be possible to cast dynamic perspective shadows onto it.

Objects which are so far in the background that the perspective doesn't change and that they do not have any light or shadow interactions with dynamic objects *might* be pre-rendered. For example, the wooden mast in the center of [this section](https://youtu.be/W_HTF0eUhb8?t=902) seems to be a pre-rendered 2d object. But it's hard to tell from video alone what background details are actual geometry and what details are just painted onto flat textures.

In general, the further something is away, the less it moves and the less light/shadow interactions you have with it, the more cheating you can get away with.

Comment: The shadows seem to warp a bit at the mast though, not sure if it's pre-rendered.